# Thumbnail image does not appear on website 

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem in my wordpress theme.
The thumbnail doesn't appear on every post.
I have a website with games and every game has a thumbnail (image) . But now the image doesn't appear. When I try to see the image I get this:

```
Invalid src mime type:
```

The problematic code is:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/thumb.php?src=<?=$thumb;?>&w=183&h=140&zc=1" class="thumb" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: If you look at the generated source of the <img> tag, what is displayed?

Comment: i wrote already. Invalid src mime type:

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood me.  Open your page and click View->Source and paste in the entire <img> tag, like <img src="foo.com/blablable?src=blablabla" /> and so on.

Comment: Hmm. An example:         <img src="http://jocuri2k.com/wp-content/themes/Games/thumb.php?src=<?=$thumb;?>&w=183&h=140&zc=1" class="thumb" alt="Billiard Blitz 2 Snooker Skool" />

Comment: Can you confirm the value of src in your querystring is actually the valid file?

Comment: That's the problem. No i can't because is not the valid file. That query string appers at all posts. Is something wrong in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing to your site I saw what the issue is.  If you look at your code, it's being generated like this:

```
<img src="http://jocuri2k.com/wp-content/themes/Games/thumb.php?src=<?=$thumb?>... ?>
```

It seems that your PHP parser isn't picking up the php in the  tag.  Try using this instead:

```
<img src="http://jocuri2k.com/wp-content/themes/Games/thumb.php?src=<?php=$thumb?>... ?>
```

It's possible your php configuration doesn't allow for "short-tags"

```
<?
  code here
?>
```

but instead require the full php tags, which are:

```
<?php
  code here
?>
```

You might be able to override this in your php.ini, but if you don't have access to that, simply use the full php tags and you should be good to go.

```
<?php echo $thumb; ?>
```

Comment: Finally nageed , what should i do ?

Comment: Try this <?php echo $thumb; ?>  The shortcut with <?= ?> only works with short open tags.